# Keep chrome javascript running even if page reload

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

I want to know if i can have some javascript code in chrome's console that runs even after page reloads. Specifically, I execute the code below where it submits a form but the thing is that loop runs only once because page reloads right after 
and chromes console will refresh. Is there anyway to keep loop running?

```
for(i=1; i< 100; i++) {
      setTimeout(function(){
         jQuery(document.getElementById("username")).attr('value', i)
          jQuery(document.getElementById("info")).attr('value', 'KKKK')
          document.getElementsByName("submit")[0].click()
      }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no. Refreshing the page clears the DOM and any JS.

You have two approaches:

1) You can try to avoid a full-page refresh from your submit; and
2) You can use cookies/session storage to "save your progress" and check for saved progress on page reload.

Comment: You can send ajax request instead of sending form.